# google map resize and center doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this code below:

```
layoutV.layout.open('east');

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    var center = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    map.setCenter(center);
});
```

`layoutV` will popout and the listener will start to resize my map and center the marker based on the new size of the window. Problem is, the map and marker only centers/resize once I drag the the mouse in the map. If I don't then nothing happens. Am I missing something or is it supposed to behave like this?

I even added the map.checkResize() after the .setCenter but nothing happnes.

Comment: A codepen or jsfiddle would make answering/troubleshooting this problem easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix it by adding a window.setTimeout before the addlistener.

```
layoutV.layout.open('east');

window.setTimeout(function() {
    map.setZoom(18);
}, 300);

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
     var latLngAdjust = map.getCenter();
     google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
     map.setCenter(latLngAdjust); 
     map.checkResize()
});
```

Now once I click a marker on the map, the window resizes and also the map and marker is at the center. ty...

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function map_resize()
{
var center = map.getCenter();                  
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); 
map.setCenter(center); 
}
```

Comment: Tried but still behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

So, the `idle` event only fires after 'panning or zooming.' Since you're triggering `resize` inside this event handler, it would only execute the code after an "idle" event (panning or zooming).

I'm not sure what the `layoutV.layout.open` bit is doing, but there is this: When you're trying to recenter a map you **must get the current center before any resizing occurs**. So, It seems that the `open('east')` is doing this, so before calling the `open('east')`, store the maps center in a var. Then, you can do your resize trigger and

```
 map.setCenter(center);
```

with the center that was stored before the containing element changed size.

Comment: Again, a jsfiddle or codepen would help greatly. Could you just copy-paste some code into one?